# Validation Rule - no Cyrillic character

Tags: validation-rule

I am creating a Validation Rule on the Account Name and Opportunity Name.
Based on Israel, the rule should accept only English letters and special characters(&,_,! etc).
IT SHOULD NOT let any user enter Hebraic letters.

I used this formule : AND(OR(ISBLANK( Name ),
NOT(REGEX(  Name  ,"^[a-z A-Z]*$"))))
BUT it does not let me enter any special characters.

Does someone have a solution in order to solve this request?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for the underlying [Java regex Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class to see more on character classes. Fundamentally you simply need to list the characters or character ranges you want to allow either directly or using "character classes" and negate it like you already do.

Comment: ...in addition to reading the docs, your goal is unclear - Cyrillic vs Hebraic vs...

Comment: I create a validation rule checking that Account Name and Opportunity Name are not in entered in Hebraic letters.

Answer (score -2):

since you want to allow the special character to be accepted then try like below

```
AND(OR(ISBLANK( Name ), REGEX( Name ,"^[a-z A-Z]*$"))
```

Comment: Huh? This is what the OP posted as not allowing symbols ("special characters")...